# Происхождение слова "ошиваться"

Tags: жаргон, этимология

"Ошиваться" - на сленге слоняться", бродить рядом с чем-то или где-то. Интересно было бы узнать происхождения этого выражения. При чем тут шитье?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется невероятным предположение о ивритских корнях. Где это простой народ их сумел нахвататься, в каких печатных или рукописных источниках смог отыскать и русифицировать? Неужели нерабочую суботу/шабат так переделал, чтобы никто не догадался? Ошивается (шляется) - *суботничает*)))
Вот есть похожий (корень ШИ) глагол *зашиться* (забегаться, задергаться, замотаться с делами : **туда-сюда, туда-сюда**), неужели и он из иврита происходит...  Зашить - забрать досками, заколотить проем, отверстие и тд. Отшить - послать человека подальше. Пришить - опять же прибить доску или панель; на жаргоне - убить, зарезать. 
*Ошиваться* - находиться рядом, болтаться около чего/кого, ходить хвостом, **как нитка за иголкой**. Простое, реальное происхождение просторечной народной лексики.

> Этимологический русскоязычный словарь
> Фасмера
> **ШВАЛЬ**
> I "портной". Из *шьваль (ср. коваль "кузнец")
> **от шить**...
> II ж., род. п. швали
> "сволочь, сброд". Едва ли из нем. Schwall
> "разбухшая масса", вопреки Горяеву...
> [Предположение о том, что ругательство
> происходит от имени новгородца Ивашки
> Шваля (нач. XVII в.), об измене которого
> сохранилось народн. предание, см. Семенов,
> "Труды Отдела др.-русск. лит.", 14, 1958, стр.
> 595 и сл.; неубедительно сближение Мокиенко
> ("Этим. иссл-я по русск. яз.", 7, 1972, стр. 155 и
> сл.) с франц. аргот. сhеvаl "грубый человек";
> **скорее к ошиваться "бродить"**. – Трубачев]

Академик Трубачев не поясняет происхождение глагола *ошиваться*, но и ни словом не упоминает о возможности заимствования из иврита.
Ивритская версия происхождения - маргинальная, фантастическая и совершенно невероятная.

Об однокоренных (корень ШИ) глаголах того же разговорно-жаргонного плана (*пришить*, *отшить*, *зашиться*) уже было сказано, добавлю только примеры :

> Д.А. Смирнов. Рассказы об А.С. Грибоедове, записанные со слов его друзей (1842-1866)
> Он ночевал в Новочеркасске, а **какую штуку отшил** в Москве, так это, действительно, можно только с грибоедовским характером.
>
> Ф. Д. Крюков. Зыбь (1909)
> ― За что! Сватается… **а я отшила**… ― Лезет?
>
> В. М. Дорошевич. Сахалин (Каторга) (1903)
> ― Ишь, черт, **пришил ни за понюх табаку**.
>
> Ф. Д. Крюков. В родных местах // «Русское Богатство», 1903
> Вот если бы теперь ему попался киргиз Мурад-бай или хоть сам прокурор, то **он «пришил бы»** каждого из них без всяких колебаний.
>
> П. Н. Краснов. От Двуглавого Орла к красному знамени (1922)
> ― **Отшили**, ― захохотал Гриценко, ― начал Анакреона проповедовать, а там это не в моде.
>
> Елизавета Скобцова (Кузьмина-Караваева). Клим Семенович Барынькин (1925)
> А так вот, **не споря, отшить полегонечку**, ― это даже, пожалуй, вежливость станичная была.
>
> Л. М. Леонов. Вор. Часть 3 (1927)
> ― Шибко тебе пошалить со мной хотелось, а **я тебя отшила**… помнишь?
>
> Илья Ильф, Евгений Петров. Золотой теленок (1931)
> И ведь сам **знает, что зашился**, хочет выкарабкаться, но такое сам нагромоздил, что не может.
>
> Василий Шукшин. Коленчатые валы (1958)
> ― **Он за-за-за… это… зашился**, а не заелся.

Просторечные слова *пришить*, *отшить*, *ошиваться*, *зашиться* являются без всяких сомнений родственными.

Answer (score 4):

Сайт  http://www.proza.ru/2013/02/03/1926  утверждает:

Скорее всего, слово оформилось на «глухих»  территориях (Вологда, Алтай – родина писателей Шукшина и Белова) как разговорное в начале XX века, в  середине века вошло в литературный язык (зафиксировано). Термин связан с деятельностью (лексикой) церкви и многочисленных северных и сибирских сект христианства в отдаленных районах (крестный ход вокруг храма – ошиваться).Так случилось,что наша религия связана с евреями, с ивритом, там и нашли корни:

Этимология иврита-

Очевидно, что в русской лексике закрепились основное значение термина – «болтаться», передвигаться где-то без дела, ходить туда-сюда.Вынужденное безделье часто-праздник(нельзя работать в религиозные праздники), а вот когда к религии было нелестное отношение, к религиозным праздникам тоже появилось отношение как к безделью - отрицательное.

а) Иврит, основное значение - О+ШИВАТЬ+СЯ = О + ШЭВЭТ вынужденное безделье; или ШЕВУТ   возвращение, идти обратно + АСА делать, пребывать; пребывание человека в состоянии бездеятельности.

б) Сопутствующая терминология иврита
В книге Даниила 11:18: «потом ОБРАТИТ (возвратит, повернёт) лицо своё к островам»; здесь применен глагол  ВЙАШЕВ возвращаться, поворачивать назад, обращаться (от ШАВ).ЙОШЕВ сидящий, житель; применятся в выражении ЙОШЕВ КЕРАНОТ – бездельник, лодырь.

ШАВАТ отдыхать, прекращать работу, бастовать; прекращать что-либо; отстранять от работы.

ШЭВЭТ прекращение работы (чего-либо), вынужденный перерыв в работе (по болезни, другим обстоятельствам), вынужденное бездействие; применяется в выражении - дружеская компания.

ШАВ, ШЕВУТ возвращающийся, возвращение, приходить в прежнее состояние, повторять, идти обратно.

Есть ещё такое бытовое объяснение от ШИТЬ:
До революции люди в основном шили одежду у портных своего соц. круга, т.е.ошивался у одного портного. Но это объясняет только значение"на одном месте", а "без дела"не объясняет. Это объясняет как раз иврит.

Answer (score 2):

ИЗ ТОЛКОВОГО СЛОВАРЯ:

ЗАШИТЬСЯ,  Разг. Делая многое, не успеть выполнить, сделать всё, что нужно. З. с делами. З. на работе.
ОШИВАТЬСЯ, Разг.-сниж. Постоянно находиться, присутствовать где-л. Где ты ошиваешься целыми днями?

Получается, что в обоих случаях мы имеем  действия, сравнимые  с движениями иглы: движение туда-сюда и движение кругами.

МНЕНИЕ ИЗ ИНТЕРНЕТА:

Глагол "ошиваться" возможно происходит от слов "шов, шить, ошивать" (когда делается шов, то игла делает "круг" с верху материи вниз под материю. "Ошиваться", значит ходить кругами или "туда-сюда".

Comment: Ошиваться - бродить, шататься, вертеться, крутиться,отираться. Также околачиваться. Значение слова заключено ИЛИ В КОРНЕ ГЛАГОЛА со значением ходьбы в разных направлениях, ИЛИ В ЗНАЧЕНИИ приставки О. Мы же не говорим "окручиваться" - это уже избыточное значение. Поэтому схема образования слова с ивритским корнем непонятна.

Answer (score 2):

Тут **Дерзкий Grantum** написал : **"Мне кажется невероятным предположение о ивритских корнях. Где это простой народ их сумел нахвататься, в каких печатных или рукописных источниках смог отыскать и русифицировать? Неужели нерабочую суботу/шабат так переделал, чтобы никто не догадался? Ошивается (шляется) - суботничает)))**. Батенька ! Да будет Вам известно , что иврит , наряду с др./греческим и латынью , входил в число 3-х священных языков ; вспомните-ка как просветитель Кирилл спорил с трёхъязычниками , отстаивая право перевода библейских книг на славянские языки (в Третьяковке есть картина на эту тему). И среди служителей православной церкви во все времена знание иврита , точнее - древнееврейского , было вполне распространено . Не говоря уж о том , что среди самих священников евреи были не ахти какой редкостью ; у меня однажды произошла небольшая дискуссия с одним батюшкой на тему допустимо ли порядочному еврею становиться выхристом ,- так он мне тут же , навскидку , назвал с полдюжины высшего уровня православных иерархов разных времен , чьё еврейское происхождение являлось известным фактом . Кроме того , самих евреев тоже было немало : по переписи 1914-го года - 4% от общего числа населения РИ , причём в крупных городах и промышленных областях этот процент несомненно был намного выше . И это данные , касающиеся только "подтверждённых" (по признаку вероисповедания) евреев , - а были ещё и *криптоевреи* ( от грч. криптос - скрытый ; не я придумал этот термин) . И , как Вы выразились , "*простой народ*" набрался о евреев очень многому - от премудростей ремесла до блатной *фени* . К слову сказать , основное ядро воровской *фени* суть переиначенный иврит или идиш . Поэтому  проявление иврита/идиша в российском жаргоне явление вполне закономерное , - такие слова , как - нахал , егоза , охламон , лебезить , старая карга , шарашкина контора - несомненно связаны с евреями . Не избежал этого влияния даже русски мат . Например , уже устаревшее слово *елда* : на иврите *йелед* означает мальчик - по аналогии чётко сопоставимо с тем , к чему это слово относится . А вот *общераспространенное слово из трёх букв* (начинающееся с Х) : на иврите это слово  **חוי** означает *чувствительный , живущий* , - обращаю ваше внимание , что сперматозоид в старой русской физиологии назывался схоже - *живчик* .

### Поэтому я целико поддерживаю ответ пользователя **Людмилы** !

---

Дополнение в ответ на поступивший комментарий Людмилы . Мне этот факт , относительно происхождения князя Владимира (в крещении Василий) Красно Солнышко ,  известен . Могу добавить , что тот Добрыня , который "крестил Новгород огнём , а Путята мечом" получил своё имя не от прилагательного "добрый" , а от мужской формы еврейского имени Дебор/Дебора . Посмотрите на имена и фамилии опричников Ивана Грозного (например , один  там звался Неустрой - думаете , это по русски ? -нет такого православного канонического имени , тут переиначенное еврейское ; то же самое про другого по фамилии Ловчиков и т.д.) , на имена и прiзвища гетманов и казачьих атаманов Запорожской Сечи (включая Богдана Хмельницкого , который суть переиначенный Гамалеил=Гамалей , - я могу это конкретно доказать) : везде и в том и в другом списке еврей на еврее ... Вообще , на эту тему можно говорить часами .

Comment: Много слов не по теме, Вам не кажется? Достаточно сделать морфологический разбор слова о/ши/ва/ть/ся, чтобы версия иноязычного происхожления  растаяла, аки дым.

Comment: Морфологический анализ можно сделать и в таком виде : о-шиват(ь)-ся . И почему "много слов не по теме" ? Вы выразили сомнение относительно возможности ивритного влияния на русский язык , а я , со своей стороны ,  попытался объяснить Вам , что роль евреев в российской (в т.ч. украинской , белорусской ) жизни была значительно выше , чем Вы себе это представляете . Тут в двух словах не выскажешься , - я , вообще , отписался предельно кратко . Занимаясь лингвистикой , надо хоть немножко чувствовать культурно-исторический фон , в котором происходило словообразование .

Comment: А если углубиться в историю и вспомнить, что князь Владимир был незаконным сыном Святослава и Малуши, дочери хазарского раввина Малка,т.е. полуеврей, то "фантастическим и невероятным" становится утверждение о нашей "далёкости" от евреев и иврита: http://kornilovd.livejournal.com/11977.html
http://www.proza.ru/2009/04/11/779  источники неофициальные, конечно,но учебникам и "Повести временных лет "не противоречат.

Comment: Даю правку-дополнение в свой ответ в ответ на Ваш комментарий .

Comment: Не вижу связи между бредом о Малуше-"еврейке" (?!) и словом *ошиваться*. Я смотрю, Новая История полным ходом пишется, скоро детям такую дурь преподавать будут... Печально.

Comment: По поводу "бреда о Малуше-еврейке" почитайте Повесть временных лет. А по поводу заимствований из иврита здесь (Барух Подольский  - человек науки, преподаватель университета):http://madan.org.il/node/463  Почему гербацизмы шмонать, шухер, малина, халява и др. не бред, а ошиваться - неправдоподобно? Антисемитство взыграло?

Comment: Это у Вас родноверие-неоязычество взыграло. Меня же полностью устраивает версия Прозоровского : Малуша и Добрыня - дети плененного древлянского князя Мала.  
Воровскую блатную лексику сюда приплетать не надо, слово *ошиваться* к ней не относится.

Answer (score 0):

Поиски еврейского следа мне тоже кажутся совершеннейшим... гм... недоразумением.
Впрочем, Грумант тоже ничего конструктивного не дает.

Пожалуй, из всего известного надо выбирать по принципу наименьшей неправдоподобности.
*Ошиваться* - вариант (фонетический?) *обшиваться*, в значении "постоянно заказывать носильные вещи", синоним - *одеваться [у такго-то портного]*. 
Вот этот признак постоянной принадлежности к чему-то мог породить *ошиваться* в значении "постоянно находиться", "крутиться" где-либо с какой-то целью. Сравните "отираться" в том же значении. Версия слаба на доказательность, но по крайней мере не столь фантастична.

Comment: Не считаю фантастичной версию после того как узнала,что из еврейского заимствованы "ботать по фене", "малина","шухер","хана", "шахер-махер"(никогда не понимала значения), "Таганка", "кипеш", "шмонать". и т.д. Это не только на форумах, но и в научной литературе, а неплохое объяснение здесь:
http://www.liveinternet.ru/community/1166452/post260712617/

Answer (score 0):

А что если изначально не "ошИваться", а "ошЕваться"? Тогда можно придти к "шевелению" и другим глаголам движения и никакого шитья.

Comment: Мне, например, не известны эти глаголы: *ош**е**вать, ош**е**ваться*. Это — как? От каких таких интересных действий мы придем к шевелению? Объясните, пожалуйста.